# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps for refs passing to/from custom hooks

Tags: react-hooks

```
const useCustomHook = (refs) => {
    const { someRef } = refs;
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(someRef.current);
    }, []); // <= react-hooks/exhaustive-deps for someRef
};

const useAnotherHook = () => {
    const anotherRef = useRef(null);
    return { anotherRef };
};

const Component = () => {
    const someRef = useRef(null);

    useCustomHook({ someRef });

    const { anotherRef } = useAnotherHook();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(anotherRef.current);
    }, []); // <= react-hooks/exhaustive-deps for anotherRef

    return (<div>Loading</div>);
};
```

When I pass ref to `useCustomHook`, inside the hook, the ref is considered as prop instead so the warning is reported from eslint. Same as exported ref from `useAnotherHook`.

How can I config eslint or change code?

Comment: someRef will always refer to the same object, so the dependency array `[]` is equivalent to `[someRef]`

Answer (score -1):

Change `useEffect` in `useCustomHook` to:

```
const useCustomHook = (refs) => {
  const { someRef } = refs;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(someRef.current);
  }, [someRef]);
};
```

and change `useEffect` in `Component` to:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(anotherRef.current);
  }, [anotherRef]);
```